# What is the bluetooth ControllerMode in /etc/bluetooth/main.conf? What is bredr?

Tags: bluetooth

A lot of advice online suggests I add the line

```
ControllerMode=bredr
```

in my `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`. What does this value do, currently it looks like it defaults to `dual`. How does changing this value, change the behavior of my bluetooth agent? What does "bredr" mean?

```
# Restricts all controllers to the specified transport. Default value
# is "dual", i.e. both BR/EDR and LE enabled (when supported by the HW).
# Possible values: "dual", "bredr", "le"
#ControllerMode = dual
```

---

While I don't think it's relevant, the error I'm [getting is the one I reported here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/712185/3285)

> Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed br-connection-profile-unavailable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've got the same error with my headphones.
I'm using pipewire myself.
Changing the controller mode option to bredr solved my issue.

- **br/edr** stands for Bluetooth basic rate/enhanced data rate (or classic bluetooth)
- **le** stands for low energy (new kind of bluetooth).

My guess is that there is some kind of negotiation process occurring between your agent and the device while the connection is made.

Dual should be ok, because including bredr, but that's not the case apparently.

I don't know if it's Pipewire's fault here, but there's something missing with the implementation of dual somewhere.